# Error to connect Spring Boot to MySQL with JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I've created a simple project with *Spring Boot* and *JPA* and *MySQL* database and when I run the main `SpringApplication` it shows this error up

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.7.RELEASE)

2019-08-19 13:13:42.928  INFO 8808 --- [           main] com.spring.votreBanque                   : Starting votreBanque on emna-PC with PID 8808 (D:\logiciel\springTest\target\classes started by emna in D:\logiciel\springTest)
2019-08-19 13:13:42.955  INFO 8808 --- [           main] com.spring.votreBanque                   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-08-19 13:14:15.272  INFO 8808 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-08-19 13:14:18.129  INFO 8808 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 1452ms. Found 5 repository interfaces.
2019-08-19 13:14:20.066  INFO 8808 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.hateoas.config.HateoasConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.hateoas.config.HateoasConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2f259fcc] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-08-19 13:14:20.085  INFO 8808 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$afa5529a] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-08-19 13:14:23.871  INFO 8808 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 2020 (http)
2019-08-19 13:14:24.166  INFO 8808 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-08-19 13:14:24.167  INFO 8808 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.22]
2019-08-19 13:14:24.963  INFO 8808 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-08-19 13:14:24.963  INFO 8808 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 41633 ms
2019-08-19 13:14:25.902  WARN 8808 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'clientMetierImplementation': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'clientrepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientRepository': Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()Ljavax/persistence/SynchronizationType;
2019-08-19 13:14:25.907  INFO 8808 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-08-19 13:14:26.003  WARN 8808 --- [           main] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
 com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:41)
2019-08-19 13:14:26.044  INFO 8808 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-08-19 13:14:26.062 ERROR 8808 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.<init>(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:665)

The following method did not exist:

    javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()Ljavax/persistence/SynchronizationType;

The method's class, javax.persistence.PersistenceContext, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/D:/javacert/javax.persistence.jar!/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.class
    jar:file:/D:/javacert/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.final.jar!/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/emna/.m2/repository/javax/persistence/persistence-api/1.0.2/persistence-api-1.0.2.jar!/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/D:/javacert/javax.persistence.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.persistence.PersistenceContext
```

This is the main class

```
package com.spring;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.spring")
public class votreBanque {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(votreBanque.class, args);

    }

}

The package `com.spring.entitie` contain these entities
```

the class `Client`:

```
package com.spring.entite;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
@Entity

public class Client implements Serializable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long code;
    private String nom;
    private String email;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="client",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<Compte> compte;
    public Client() {

    }
    public Long getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(Long code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }
    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public Collection<Compte> getCompte() {
        return compte;
    }
    public void setCompte(Collection<Compte> compte) {
        this.compte = compte;
    }
    public Client(String nom, String email) {
        super();
        this.nom = nom;
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

The class `Compte`:

```
package com.spring.entite;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorColumn;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="TYPE_CPT",discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING,length=2)
public class Compte implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String codeCompte;
    private Date dateCreation;
    private double solde;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CODE_CLI")
    private Client client;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="compte")
    private Collection<Operation> operations;
    public Compte() {
        super();

    }
    public String getCodeCompte() {
        return codeCompte;
    }
    public void setCodeCompte(String codeCompte) {
        this.codeCompte = codeCompte;
    }
    public Date getDateCreation() {
        return dateCreation;
    }
    public void setDateCreation(Date dateCreation) {
        this.dateCreation = dateCreation;
    }
    public double getSolde() {
        return solde;
    }
    public void setSolde(double solde) {
        this.solde = solde;
    }
    public Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }
    public void setClient(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }
    public Collection<Operation> getOperations() {
        return operations;
    }
    public void setOperations(Collection<Operation> operations) {
        this.operations = operations;
    }
    public Compte(String codeCompte, Date dateCreation, double solde, Client client) {
        super();
        this.codeCompte = codeCompte;
        this.dateCreation = dateCreation;
        this.solde = solde;
        this.client = client;
    }

}
```

The class `CompteCourant` which extends `Compte`:

```
package com.spring.entite;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CC")
public class CompteCourant extends Compte {
    private double decouvert;

    public CompteCourant(double decouvert) {
        super();
        this.decouvert = decouvert;
    }

    public CompteCourant(String codeCompte, Date dateCreation, double solde, Client client, double decouvert) {
        super(codeCompte, dateCreation, solde, client);
        this.decouvert = decouvert;
    }

    public double getDecouvert() {
        return decouvert;
    }

    public void setDecouvert(double decouvert) {
        this.decouvert = decouvert;
    }




}
```

The class `CompteEpargne` another sub-class of `Compte`:

```
package com.spring.entite;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CE")
public class CompteEpargne extends Compte {
    private double taux;

    public double getTaux() {
        return taux;
    }

    public void setTaux(double taux) {
        this.taux = taux;
    }

    public CompteEpargne() {
        super();

    }

    public CompteEpargne(String codeCompte, Date dateCreation, double solde, Client client, double taux) {
        super(codeCompte, dateCreation, solde, client);
        this.taux = taux;
    }

}
```

The class `Operation`:

```
package com.spring.entite;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;

import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorColumn;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="TYPE_OP",discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING,length=1)
public abstract class Operation implements Serializable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long numero;
    private Date dateOperation;
    private double montant;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CODE_CPTE")
    private Compte compte;
    public Operation() {
        super();

    }
    public Long getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }
    public void setNumero(Long numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }
    public Date getDateOperation() {
        return dateOperation;
    }
    public void setDateOperation(Date dateOperation) {
        this.dateOperation = dateOperation;
    }
    public double getMontant() {
        return montant;
    }
    public void setMontant(double montant) {
        this.montant = montant;
    }
    public Compte getCompte() {
        return compte;
    }
    public void setCompte(Compte compte) {
        this.compte = compte;
    }
    public Operation(Date dateOperation, double montant, Compte compte) {
        super();
        this.dateOperation = dateOperation;
        this.montant = montant;
        this.compte = compte;
    }


}
```

The class `Retrait` which extends `Operation`:

```
package com.spring.entite;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("R")
public class Retrait extends Operation {

    public Retrait() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Retrait(Date dateOperation, double montant, Compte compte) {
        super(dateOperation, montant, compte);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }




}
```

The class `Versement` which extends `Operation` too:

```
package com.spring.entite;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("V")
public class Versement extends Operation {

    public Versement() {
        super();

    }

    public Versement(Date dateOperation, double montant, Compte compte) {
        super(dateOperation, montant, compte);

    }

}
```

and `package com.spring.dao`

```
  package com.spring.dao;
        import com.spring.entite.Client;
        import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

        public interface clientRepository extends JpaRepository<Client, Long>{

        }






   package com.spring.dao;

        import com.spring.entite.Compte;
        import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

        public interface compteRespository extends JpaRepository<Compte, String> {

        }




      package com.spring.dao;
        import com.spring.entite.Employe;
        import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

        public interface employeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employe, Long> {

        }




      package com.spring.dao;

        import com.spring.entite.Groupe;
        import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

        public interface groupeRepository extends JpaRepository<Groupe, Long> {

        }






   package com.spring.dao;


        import com.spring.entite.Operation;
        import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

        public interface operationRepository extends JpaRepository<Operation, String> {

        }


package com.spring.metier
package com.spring.metier;

import com.spring.entite.*;
import java.util.*;
public interface ClientMetier {
    public Client saveClient(Client c);
    public List<Client> listeClient();

}
```

package `com.spring.metier`

```
package com.spring.metier;
import com.spring.entite.*;
import java.util.*;
public interface ClientMetier {
    public Client saveClient(Client c);
    public List<Client> listeClient();

}
```

class clientMetierImplementation how implements ClientMetier

```
  package com.spring.metier;

    import java.util.List;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    import com.spring.dao.clientRepository;
    import com.spring.entite.Client;
    @Service
    public class clientMetierImplementation implements ClientMetier {

        @Autowired(required=true)
        private clientRepository clientrepository;

        @Override
        public Client saveClient(Client c) {

            return clientrepository.save(c);
        }

        @Override
        public List<Client> listeClient() {
            return clientrepository.findAll();
        }

    }


package `com.spring.services`

package com.spring.services;

    import java.util.List;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    import com.spring.entite.Client;
    import com.spring.metier.ClientMetier;

    @RestController
    @Component
    public class ClientRestService {
        @Autowired(required=true)
        private ClientMetier clientmetier;
          @RequestMapping(value="/clients",method=RequestMethod.POST)

        public Client saveClient(@RequestBody Client c) {
            return clientmetier.saveClient(c);
        }
         @RequestMapping(value="/clients",method=RequestMethod.GET)     
        public List<Client> listeClient() {
            return clientmetier.listeClient();
        }

    }
```

I spent one day looking for the solution, but I don't find  what is causing the error.

Comment: to me, looks like there is a mismatch in the hibernate and persistence api jars, you need to match right versions.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty self-explanatory:

> Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.persistence.PersistenceContext

I would use Maven as a sole source of dependencies, i.e. remove `D:/javacert/javax.persistence.jar` and `D:/javacert/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.final.jar` from the classpath and only use the dependency from Maven. Are you building with an IDE? If yes, please correct the classpath. If no, please remove any additional dependencies other than the `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Your Application is finding `javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()`from multiple location here are the ways you can resolve this error

1. Delete all the jar and reimport it.
2. try doing `mvn clean install` in the source directory of your project.
3. try deleting M2 repository and build the project again.

> C:/Users/emna/.m2

4. Try deleting jar included externally (other than pom.xml)

> D:/javacert/javax.persistence.jar

5. OR

> D:/javacert/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.final.jar

UPDATE :

The error

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.sid.entities.Operation

Suggests that it cannot find identifier which will uniquely identify you operation entity. 
This mean that you need to put @Id annotation of package `javax.persistence.Id` in your operation class.

By looking at your code

1. I see that you have used @Id of package `org.springframework.data.annotation.Id` instead of package `javax.persistence.Id`
2. try changing the package as hibernate needs @Id annotation of `javax.persistence` package.

Also please upvote if you find my answer helpful in anyway.

Comment: m2 repository may vary depending on your environment.

Comment: Yes you are correct but looking at the error it suggested that application was confused to select jar as there were multiple jars, so deleting m2 would have been one of the solutions.